# SQL Server Management Studio Express, присоединение БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте!
У меня вопрос в следующем.

На компьютере было установлено:
Среда SQL Server Management Studio Express
Microsoft SQL Server 2005.
возможности сделать BackUp не было, поэтому сохранили физически только файлы БД с расширением .mdf

Так вот при переустановке windows и SQL Server Management Studio Express
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 необходимо вернуть БД к работе.
Суть в том, что присоединить бызу не получается, SQL Server Management Studio Express выдаёт ошибку:

> Failed to update database "test" because the database is read-only
>   (Error: 3906).

что делать в данной ситуации?

Comment: А вы detach перед этим делали? Сейчас в списке баз сервера есть база с таким именем?

Comment: программно ничего не делалось!
файлы БД были просто скопированы физически файлами в хранилище, после этого была переустановка виндовс
также сохранили и системные БД, это те что лежать по дресу:
programm files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Template Data
с именами: master.mdf model.mdf и т.д.

Comment: Хм. по уму надо было хотя бы отсоединить. Раз системные базы просто скопировали, то видимо и в списке есть какая то запись о базе test? Предлагаю ее удалить и потом сделать attach

Comment: извините, но я не понимаю вопроса

Comment: Подключаетесь к серверу, смотрите список баз на нем. Есть в этом списке test, который хотите восстановить?

Comment: в SQL Server Management Studio Express присоединенная база есть, но рядом с её именем надпись (Только для чтения). при клике на эту БД окно программы становится не активным, а курсор мыши с часиками, типа происходят вычесления. Я оставил в таком состоянии на ночь, но ничего не произошло, пришлось грубо закрывать программу из диспетчера задач.

При присоединении этой базы SQL Server Management Studio Express выдал ошибку: Filed to update database "test" because the database i read-only (Error: 3906). после этого имя базы появилось в списке БД

Answer (score 1):

**Решение:**

*- Поменял Network Service на Local System*

*- засунул файлы моей БД в папку "program files" к "SQL server" ...... "data", далее всё прекрасно присоединилось..*

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите правую кнопку мыши на этой базе. Выберите `properties`. Зайдите на вкладку `options`. Переключатель положения `read only` находится внизу списка опций в блоке `State`.

Comment: опять выдаёт ошибку, "Невозможно вывести данное окно, база в режиме восстановления, подождите пока процесс завершится".
При первичном присоединении БД уже вывелась ошибка Filed to update database "test" because the database i read-only (Error: 3906).